# What is the most secure way to know a secure web request is made by an iPhone

Tags: ios, request, asihttprequest

What is the most secure way for a web server to know that the request has been posted by an iPhone, and by nothing else. (https POST request made by ASIHttpRequest).

Thanks,
Niels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no secure way to do this. It is relatively easy to write a client that "impersonates" an iPhone client down to the last byte of the request.

Comment: and is it possible to hide a string in the apps ? In a .h for instance.

Comment: If you want to authenticate a specific app rather than the iPhone, then that's a different question altogether. You can do that with a client-side certificate embedded in the app, though of course a smart enough opponent can simply reverse-engineer your app and extract the certificate.